# How to pass DateTime from C# proxy client to Java Web Service accepting as Date and Time only

Tags: c#

I have developed a proxy client in C# from the java web service's WSDL file with the help of wsdl.exe tool. The wsdl file contains xsd:date and xsd:time which maps to DateTime members in the C# proxy client code. I need to send only the current date and time to the Java's web service. But the DateTime contains both date and time which is not accepted by the web service. I don't need to bother about timezone issues and all since both client and services are in same time zone.

Comment: Does the web service fail if you simply pass the DateTime object representing the current time and date to both parameters? The usual convention in .Net is to use DateTime for both Dates and Times and just ignore the other part.

Answer (score 0):

WCF does not supports `xs:date` and `xs:time` by default, it use the `xs:datetime`. You can use the `XmlSerializerFormat` adding this attribute to the ServiceContract interface, but datetime should be field of complex type.

Another interesting solution, it's proposed by robsosno in this article:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WcfDate.aspx